# Amicable pairs: any use for them yet?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

As an exercise in Python programming I've written a script that finds amicable pairs, and I've had fun doing so. But I'm wondering if amicable pairs have a use, in mathematics or elsewhere?

As a reminder:
Amicable numbers are two different numbers so related that the sum of the proper divisors of each is equal to the other number. (A proper divisor of a number is a positive integer divisor other than the number itself. For example, the proper divisors of $6$ are $1$, $2$, and $3$.)

For example, the smallest pair of amicable numbers is $(220, 284)$; for the proper divisors of $220$ are $1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $10$, $11$, $20$, $22$, $44$, $55$ and $110$, of which the sum is $284$; and the proper divisors of $284$ are $1$, $2$, $4$, $71$, and $142$, of which the sum is $220$.
(from the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_number))

The first few amicable pairs, according to *Math World*, are:
$(220, 284)$, $(1184, 1210)$, $(2620, 2924)$, $(5020, 5564)$, $(6232, 6368)$, $(10744, 10856)$, $(12285, 14595)$, $(17296, 18416)$, $(63020, 76084)$

Comment: Number theory is almost never about math we need or can use in real life. Cryptograhy might be one of the very few exceptions.

Comment: One can to conjecture that $\psi(n(2n+1)(2(n+1)^2-1))=4(n+1)^4$, where here the sequence by Vicenzo Librandi is explicit as particular value of the Dedekind psi function $\psi(k)$, then $n$ belongs to his sequence A153477 from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. One can to deduce more nice expresions involving the Euler's totient function and the Dedekind function and the integers $p+1,q+1$ and $r+1$. My belief is that an idea is to observe the form of such primes/integers and evoke values of arithmetic functions related to visible points and lattices (and arithmetic billiards).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, John Conway says no.

> For example, John Conway says they are not very useful mathematically:

> The only application or use for these numbers is the original one -
> you insert a pair of amicable numbers into a pair of amulets, of
> which you wear one yourself and give the other to your beloved!

From [Dr. Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223110823/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52560.html).

Answer (score 3):

As a Math teacher, I find them useful as an introduction to the whimsical side of math.  Sometimes, but not always, the ninth and tenth graders appreciate that mathematicians sometimes explore things just for the fun of discovery.